# TLS сокет на python. Получил я шифрование пересылаемых данных или только проверку сертификатов при соединении?

Tags: python, сокет, шифрование, rsa, tls

У меня есть шаблон кода из учебника по теме TLS сокетов и применения алгоритма вычисления ключа шифрования по Диффи-Хеллману.

В блоке обработчика входящих сообщений мы видим такую строку:

```
encrypted_key = conn.recv(4096).decode()
```

что прямо нам говорит: на вход мы получаем зашифрованный ключ. Дальше надо его расшифровать, и делай чего хочешь. Так вот, я никак не могу определиться, что от меня хотел автор учебника, и как это надо сделать-то грамотно? В том плане, что за ключ я по плану должен получить? Т.е., надо прописать на стороне клиента алгоритм генерации симметричного ключа и его шифрование? Но тогда это уже ненадежно и не относится к Диффи-Хеллману...

Данный вопрос истекает из следующей непонятки: а чего я вообще добился таким кодом? Создал сокет, создал обертку TLS и завернул сокет в обертку. Я точно проверил сертификаты при подключении, а значит обменялся ими. Но я не утверждал алгоритма шифрования и не нашел ничего подобного в документации к библиотеке, значит текущая обертка TLS лишь позволяет автоматизировать обмен сертификатами? Блок генерации ключа по Диффи-Хеллману нужно прописать вручную (вручную - отсылая команды к openssl)? Или для этого все же есть предустановленные методы ? Или я что-то где-то упустил?

Полный код сервера:

```
import socket
import ssl
import threading
 
client_cert = 'path/to/client.crt'
server_key = 'path/to/server.key'
server_cert = 'path/to/server.crt'
port = 8080
 
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=client_cert)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=server_cert, keyfile=server_key)
context.options |= ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE
context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_2
 
def handler(conn):
       encrypted_key = conn.recv(4096).decode()
      #------------------------------------------------
      # Добавьте сюда код для расшифровки
      #------------------------------------------------
      conn.send(decrypted_key.encode())
      conn.close()
 
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
      sock.bind(('', port))
      sock.listen(5) 
      with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True) as ssock:
            while True:
                   conn, addr = ssock.accept() 
                   print(addr)
                   handlerThread = threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(conn,)) 
                   handlerThread.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encrypted_key, decrypted_key не относятся к связи. это просто какие-то данные. Их можно использовать для установки сеанса шифрованной связи, но явно на это ничего не указывает. Скорее всего просто "секретные" данные.

А вот wrap_socket делает обмен сертификатами, генерацию сессионных ключей и обмен ими по Диффи-Хеллману. В ssock не передаются никакие ключи и сертификаты - всё это убрано в контекст ssl. Данные попавшие в ssoсk шифруются и отправляются через sock.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял: 
- контекст ssl по умолчанию использует алгоритм Диффи-Хеллмана на эллиптических кривых (иначе ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE не имеет смысла); 
- если такой трафик перехватить, он будет зашифрован по ДХ; 
- после закрытия сокета\соединения сессионный секретный ключ удаляется; 
- блок "добавьте сюда код для расшифровки" вероятно предполагает дополнительный уровень шифрования и скорее излишен.

Comment: Да. Сессионными ключами обменялись по ДХ. Второй уровень шифрования часто  нужен для того чтоб в случае митм данные не были бы доступны. Или ещё если приложение хранит данные где-то в открытом виде.